# Ruby on Rails - ActiveRecord Where

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little rusty on ruby on rails, and hoping someone can give me a little guidance on what i'm missing.  In my "order" model, I have the following defined:

```
def send_post_action_email
     return ProjectEmailLogs.where(project_id: self.project.id)
end
```

Inside of a controller helper, I am trying to use this as part of an if test.  Currently I have:

```
if order.send_post_action_email
   //Do Stuff
end
```

The above test does not seem to be working.  I've tried playing with things like `?` and `any` but still can't get it to work.  Basically, if that where lookup finds any matching results, the test should be true - otherwise false.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord where clause returns array of matched objects. In case of no objects found, it return an empty array.

`order.send_post_action_email.empty?` will check if results are empty

Try this

`if !order.send_post_action_email.empty?`

`//Do Stuff`

`end`

Comment: Better to use `.exists?` instead of `.empty?`. Does the same thing and doesn't require a negation.

Comment: aditionally to the comment, here is a benchmark about `present?`, `any?` and `exists?` methods https://www.ombulabs.com/blog/benchmark/performance/rails/present-vs-any-vs-exists.html